# Profile Settings side-navbar contains a bad link on the "Newsletters" tab

Tags: bug, profile-page

I happened across this one by chance while going through the settings. If you go to your profile on the main site then "Edit Profile and Settings" -> "Newsletters", the link to "Job Alerts" links to [`https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/job-alerts?`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/job-alerts?) (which is a 404) rather than `https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/job-alerts/{youridhere}`. I checked and it specifically occurs on the Newsletters tab. The link should be updated to the latter one so it no longer 404s.

It might also be worth noting I am not subscribed to any newsletters. Not sure if that changes the way that link is rendered (I've seen weirder bugs before).

Comment: This appears to have been fixed along with https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366934/4504895