# Clicking on 'Job Alerts' under my Email Settings returns a 404

Tags: support, bug, hyperlinks, profile-page

1. Go to Edit Profile and Settings
2. Under Email Settings, select 'Job Alerts'
3. Receive 404

(URL is `https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/job-alerts?`)

[image]

Comment: This has been fixed